# Ajax Jquery hitting error event when I receive JSON from Python Flask API

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have set up a basic Python Flask API

```
import flask
from flask import jsonify
from camera_controller import camera_controller

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


app.config["JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR"] = False

app.register_blueprint(camera_controller, url_prefix='/camera')


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify({"result": "OK"})


app.run()
```

I've tested this in Chrome, FF and IE
Response Headers:

```
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 12:25:18 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.2

Status Code: 200 OK
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "result": "OK"
}
```

I then make a request from Jquery but the response is being handled by the error function even though the response status is 200:

```
private fetchFrame() {            
    $.ajax({                
            url: `http://localhost:5000/test`,
            method: "get",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

The contents of the exception:

```
readyState: 0
status: 0
responseText: ""
statusText: "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Might just be a typo but it looks like the apostrophes around your url parameter are actually backticks.

Also, Flask usually only needs `url: '/test'` AFAIK, since you're referring to a Flask-internal route. Might be different `private fetchFrame()`, though. I'm not sure what exactly that does.

Comment: It's actually typescript and is transpiled into javascript. The backticks are replace with standard single quotes and the private is replaced with 'function'. The given code is from a simplified. I use string interpolation to generate the longer url.

Comment: Could you output the full console error message for us and also what you get in Flask with `app.run(debug=True)`?

Comment: Thanks for your help Dennis. It turned out to be a cross origin problem. I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

I needed to add:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response headers
```

So I edited my method as follows:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():

    response = flask.Response(json.dumps({"result": "OK"}), content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8');
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response
```